# An error has occurred which Windows PowerShell cannot handle

Tags: powershell, invoke-command

When i'm trying to do remote connection using invoke command
`icm -cn $ips -Credential $crd {hostname}`
i'm getting error as

```
An error has occurred which Windows PowerShell cannot handle. A remote session might have ended.
```

Comment: Please show us the **FULL** error message. Also are you getting this error when using `Enter-PSSession`?

Comment: yeah, getting the same error for enter-pssession as well `Enter-PSSession : An error has occurred which Windows PowerShell cannot 
handle. A remote session might have ended.
At line:11 char:1
+ Enter-PSSession -ComputerName $ips -Credential $crd
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [Enter-PSSession], PSRe 
   motingDataStructureException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Management.Automation.Remoting.PSRemoting 
   DataStructureException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.EnterPSSessionCommand`

Comment: If this is on VM's, read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/user-guide/powershell-direct#error-a-remote-session-might-have-ended)

Comment: I have already checked that article but not much helpful.

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

Potential causes:

- The virtual machine exists but is not running
- The VM does not support PowerShell Direct (VM needs to be: Windows 10, Windows Server 2016, or later)
- PowerShell isn't available in the guest yet

  - The operating system hasn't finished booting
  - The operating system can't boot correctly
  - Some boot time event needs user input

From: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/user-guide/powershell-direct#error-a-remote-session-might-have-ended